# NPM is ignoring jQuery version in package.json

Tags: jquery, npm, package.json

So I'm not sure how this is happening, but when I run 'npm install' in an Angular 4 project of mine, it's completely ignoring the version of jQuery I have specified in my packages.json file, and it's installing version 1.7.4.

I have 2.2.4 specified in package.json -- I'm running bootstrap 3.3.7, and any jQuery version newer than that will break bootstrap.

The weird thing is that, when npm is running install, I get a warning message: npm WARN deprecated jQuery@1.7.4: This is deprecated. Please use 'jquery' (all lowercase).  But I have no idea where thats coming from.  There is nothing I'm aware of that's specifying jQuery 1.7.4 anywhere.

Any ideas?

(Edit 10-Aug-2017: Below is my package.json file, as requested. Thanks.)

```
{
  "name": "smartadmin",
  "version": "0.4.5",
  "license": "WRAPBOOTSTRAP",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build",
    "build:prod": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot=false",
    "build:aot": "./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot",
    "build:aot2": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --prod --aot",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev": "./node_modules/.bin/ng serve",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/ng test",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "ng": "ng",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^6.3.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "X-editable": "github:vitalets/x-editable",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-colorpicker": "^2.5.1",
    "bootstrap-duallistbox": "^3.0.6",
    "bootstrap-markdown": "^2.10.0",
    "bootstrap-progressbar": "^0.9.0",
    "bootstrap-slider": "^9.8.0",
    "bootstrap-tagsinput": "^0.7.1",
    "bootstrap-timepicker": "^0.5.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "clockpicker": "^0.0.7",
    "clone": "^2.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debounce": "^1.0.2",
    "dropzone": "^4.3.0",
    "dygraphs": "^2.0.0",
    "fuelux": "^3.16.0",
    "he": "^1.1.1",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.12",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.1.7",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jquery-color": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery-jcrop": "^0.9.13",
    "jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",
    "jquery-ui-npm": "^1.12.0",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
    "jquery.maskedinput": "^1.4.1",
    "markdown": "^0.5.0",
    "morris.js": "^0.5.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-popover": "^0.0.16",
    "nouislider": "^9.2.0",
    "raphael": "^2.2.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "scriptjs": "^2.5.8",
    "select2": "^4.0.3",
    "smartadmin-plugins": "^1.0.20",
    "summernote": "^0.8.3",
    "to-markdown": "^3.0.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.3",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/grigson/smartadmin-angular-2"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://bitbucket.org/grigson/smartadmin-angular-2/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

***UPDATE (14-Aug-2017)***

I completely deleted my nodejs and npm installs using instructions I found here: [How do I completely uninstall Node.js, and reinstall from beginning (Mac OS X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x)

Here are the commands I used:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp /opt/local/bin/node opt/local/include/node /opt/local/lib/node_modules

lsbom -f -l -s -pf /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.node.pkg.bom | while read f; do sudo rm /usr/local/${f}; done

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules /var/db/receipts/org.nodejs.*
```

I also deleted a few other 'node' and 'npm' folders and files that I found while browsing the various places mentioned in that link above (including a `/Users/[myusername]/.npm` folder that existed)...

Then I downloaded the node v6.11.2 .pkg file from nodejs.org, and installed it.  It comes with version 3.-something of npm, so I updated npm (`npm install -g npm`) to version 5.3.0.

Then I installed Angular/CLI 1.3.0 (the newest release as of today) `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.3.0` (I updated my package.json above to reflect this new version of Angular, btw.)

Then I went into my Angular project folder and ran `npm install`.

AND IT INSTALLED JQUERY 1.7.4 AGAIN!!!!!   WTF?!!!!!!

I copied my package.json file to an empty folder and ran `npm install` and it did the same thing -- jQuery 1.7.4.

Ridiculous!!!  WTF is going on here?!!

If anyone has ANY ideas, I'm open to ANY suggestions.  This is nuts!

Comment: Can you please post your packages.json file?

Comment: Done.  I edited the original post to include my package.json file.  Thanks.

Comment: @LaurenceMacNeill it worked perfectly fine for me,i copied ur package json and ran npm install and it installed jquery 2.2.4 version without any warning...which npm version u using? and node version?

Comment: So I just put that `package.json` file in a blank folder and ran `npm install`.  It did the **same thing** with the incorrect version of jquery!!  What the heck?!!

I'm running version 6.11.2 of NodeJS, and version 5.3.0 of NPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently npm turned case sensitive or something and when npm reads the the library jquery.color it loads the old deprecated jQuery 1.7.4 ... I was able to get it to work with the jquery.color reference by running this

```
npm install
npm install jquery
```

Which will force the right version of jquery to be installed after the wrong one is installed

Answer (score 4):

Ok -- I finally found why it's doing this...

Apparently the jQuery color-picker has a jQuery 1.7.4 dependency built-in somewhere...

When I removed `"jquery-color": "^1.0.0",` from my package.json file, it installed jQuery 2.2.4 instead of 1.7.4!!  So at least I figured out where it's getting jQuery 1.7.4 from...

I still don't know why that dependency is forcing npm to install the wrong version of jQuery for the entire project, though...  That's just weird...

Comment: I found that there's an unreleased newer version of jquery-color in npm, 3.0.0-alpha.1.  I can't vouch for whether it's safe to use, but switching to it does remove the broken dependency.

Comment: Good to know that they've fixed the dependency in the newest version.  Now we just wait until it's no longer alpha- or beta-testing.  Shouldn't be too long, I would think.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: To npm install, ^1.0.0 (format: major.minor.patch) means install the latest version at the minor level (that's what the ^ means). ~1.0.0 would mean install the latest version at the patch level. It took me a while and a fair bit of hair pulling to twig this. Hope that helps anyone else coming across this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `node_modules` folder and do a `npm cache clean`.

Run `npm install` again

Also check in your index.html file if you are not accidentally overwrite the jQuery version with a CDN line.

Comment: Yep.  I've done all of that.  I had to use `npm cache clean --force` because I'm using a version of npm greater than 5.0.0.  And then I checked it with `npm cache verify` and it showed 0 bytes in the cache.  I have **no** idea why it's doing this!  Totally crazy!

Comment: And your index.html page is clean?

Comment: I checked my index.html and there is no reference to jQuery in it.  I copied my package.json file to a completely empty folder and ran `npm install` there.  It still installed the same incorrect version of jQuery with no index.html file in there.